# FCM Cannot receive messages on WebApp

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Well, simply put, I cannot receive messages via my WebApp using JS. I am receiving tokens and I am able to send messages via Firebase console to the WebApp's token, but I am not getting any receiving.

Here is my JS Code:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBLCsBQVXLsDjPhjdkvJVMGyDUcfWrFtQU",
    authDomain: "php-test-project-78c66.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://php-test-project-78c66.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "php-test-project-78c66",
    storageBucket: "php-test-project-78c66.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "856365479454"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

$(document).ready(function(){
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.requestPermission().then(function() {
        console.log("Permitted");
        return messaging.getToken();
    }).then(function(token) {
            console.log(token);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Not Permitted");
    });
    messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
      console.log("TEST");
      console.log("Message received. ", payload);
    });
});
```

Upon sending message via Firebase Console, I do not receive anything. I send by using TokenID.

PS: The keys are of a Dev Testing App, hence I kept it in. If admins consider this a problem then you may remove it.

Comment: Did you try sending via API ? is yes, could you report the error ?
If there is no error and you received a message-id you can contact Firebase Support

Comment: Yes, I was able to send via the FCM API. I guess t was something related to the Firebase sending procedure.

Comment: If via API works but not via web console you can report the problem to Firebase. Sorry but I am not fully knowledgable on this aspect (Web Console + Web App token)